# Access to protected member variable from derived inner class in a templated parent class

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

I'm getting this error when trying to compile this:

```
template <typename T>
struct Temp
{
    struct BaseIterator
    {
    protected:
        int  pos;
        BaseIterator() : pos(0) {}
    };

    struct LeafIterator : public BaseIterator
    {
        int * operator * () { return &pos; }

        LeafIterator() : BaseIterator() {}
    };
};
```

Returns:

```
prog.cpp: In member function ‘int * Temp<T>::LeafIterator::operator*() const’:
prog.cpp:24:52: error: ‘pos’ was not declared in this scope
             int * operator * () { return &pos; }
```

The same code without the parent `Temp` structure works fine, and so does the code when the `Temp` structure is not template. Similarly, even if the base's member is `public`, I still get the compiler's error.

I know that I can refer to inherited members via `this->pos`, but it's a real pain to add `this->` everywhere in the code.

How can I access the base members without having to prefix all of them via `this->` ?

Edit: The `BaseIterator` is simply holding common member for many different (but working similarly) iterators. I can duplicate all members in all iterators and be done with it, but I wanted to reuse a common/generic interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `using` declaration.

```
template <typename T>
struct Temp
{
    struct BaseIterator
    {
    protected:
        int  pos;
        BaseIterator() : pos(0) {}
    };

    struct LeafIterator : public BaseIterator
    {
        using BaseIterator::pos;
        int * operator * () { return &pos; }

        LeafIterator() : BaseIterator() {}
    };
};

int main()
{
    Temp<int>::LeafIterator leaf_iterator;
}
```

This compiles fine in GCC 8.2.0.

Comment: This is probably the most concise solution. It still need to replicate all the members in each child (so it's as easier to declare them in `LeafIterator` at first and remove inheritance), but I guess that's unavoidable.

Answer (score 2):

> How can I access the base members without having to prefix all of them via `this->` ?

You can create a `private` accessor:

```
class LeafIterator : public BaseIterator
{
private:
    int& pos() { return this->pos; }

public:
    int * operator * () { return &pos(); }

    LeafIterator() : BaseIterator() {}
};
```

Comment: True, but it's as ugly as `this->`, since I'd have to rewrite all base members in the child class, and still modify all calls to these members to add parenthesis (I can then directly remove the base class, it'll be faster)

Comment: @xryl669: I can't think of any other solution. Either embrace the extra syntax or move `LeafIterator` and `BaseIterator` outside of `Temp` (if possible), maybe in a `detail::` namespace

Comment: In this toy code it'd be possible. But the iterators need to refer to T somehow so, no, it's not possible in real life.